# How to get content of unnamed nested div inside div with class? (Use Scrapy or BeautifulSoup)

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to obtain the nested unnamed div inside:

> div class="pod three columns closable content-sizes clearfix">

The nested unnamed div is also the first div inside the div above (see image)

I have tried the following:

```
for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'pod three columns closable content-sizes clearfix'}):
     print(div.text)
```

The length of

> soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'pod three columns closable
> content-sizes clearfix'})

is just one despite this div having many nested divs. So, the for-loop runs only once and prints everything.

I need all the text inside only the first nested div div (see image):

1. Project...
2. Reference Number...
3. Other text

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="pod three columns closable content-sizes clearfix">
    <div>
        <b>Project: ...</b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <b>Reference Number: ...</b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <b>Other text ...</b>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div>
        Other text I don't want
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(
    soup.select_one("div.pod.three.columns > div").get_text(
        strip=True, separator="\n"
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
Project: ...
Reference Number: ...
Other text ...
```

---

Or without CSS selector:

```py
print(
    soup.find(
        "div",
        attrs={"class": "pod three columns closable content-sizes clearfix"},
    )
    .find("div")
    .get_text(strip=True, separator="\n")
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Both work but the table and the text in the other nested divs is also printed. I'll make a regex to parse the text I want.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
result = soup.find('div', class_ = "pod three columns closable content-sizes clearfix").find("div")

print(result.text)
```

output:-

```
  Project: .............
  Reference Number: ....
  Other text ...........
```

Comment: This still prints the table and the text in the other nested divs. I'm trying to make a regex now to get the first three lines.

Comment: you can add recursive parameters rescursive=False